# Did Future Zen-Oh destroy only Future Universe 7 or all 12 Future universes?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

If he destroyed only Future Universe 7 then other 11 Universes do not have a ruler God now because he went to the past, isn't that very bad?

If he destroyed all 12 Universes then why did he do that if only Universe 7 was polluted by Zamasu?